# Sending Email by using Oracle stored procedure and get attachment through Application Server

Tags: stored-procedures, sendmail

I need to send out an email with PDF file attachments by using stored procedure.
But the PDF files is located at the application server and not in database server.
I  had written one stored procedure which can completely send the email with attachment, but the PDF files is located at database server.

Now I want the way to get the PDF file from application server.
Any suggestion?

Below is the stored procedure I am using to send the email and get the PDF files located at database server.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TestEmail AS

p_recipient VARCHAR2(500) := '<rubbycg@gmail.com>';
p_subject VARCHAR2(500) := 'Test attachement';
p_message VARCHAR2(500) := 'This is email body';
p_filename VARCHAR2(500) := '123.pdf';
--
-- Make sure directory object is valid and your PDF file is in it.
--
p_directory VARCHAR2(100) := 'TESTPDF';

v_msg VARCHAR2(32000);
src_file bfile;
i integer := 1;
v_raw raw(57);
v_length integer := 0;
v_buffer_size integer := 57;
v_mailconn utl_smtp.connection;
gc_crlf VARCHAR2(4) := chr(13) || chr(10);
gc_lf VARCHAR2(4) := chr(10);
gc_mailhost varchar2(30) := '10.200.1.1' ;
BOUNDARY CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := '7D81B75CCC90D2974F7A1CBD';
FIRST_BOUNDARY CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := '--' || BOUNDARY || utl_tcp.CRLF;
LAST_BOUNDARY CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := '--' || BOUNDARY || '--' ||
utl_tcp.CRLF;
MULTIPART_MIME_TYPE CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="'||BOUNDARY ||'"';

BEGIN

v_mailconn := utl_smtp.open_connection(gc_mailhost,25);
utl_smtp.helo(v_mailconn,gc_mailhost);
utl_smtp.mail(v_mailconn,'apps_notification@toray.com.my');
utl_smtp.rcpt(v_mailconn,p_recipient);
utl_smtp.open_data (v_mailconn);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'From: ' || p_recipient || utl_tcp.crlf );
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'To: ' || p_recipient || utl_tcp.crlf );
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || utl_tcp.crlf );


utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'|| BOUNDARY || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, utl_tcp.crlf );

utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, FIRST_BOUNDARY);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, ' charset=US-ASCII'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, utl_tcp.crlf );   
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'This is email body' || utl_tcp.CRLF);   


utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, FIRST_BOUNDARY);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Content-Type' || ': ' || 'application/pdf' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; ' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, ' filename="' || p_filename || '"' || utl_tcp.crlf);


utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.crlf );
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, utl_tcp.crlf );

src_file := bfilename(p_directory, p_filename);
dbms_lob.fileopen(src_file, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
v_length := dbms_lob.getlength(src_file);



while i < v_length loop

   dbms_lob.read( src_file, v_buffer_size, i, v_raw );
   utl_smtp.write_raw_data( v_mailconn, utl_encode.base64_encode(v_raw) );
   i := i + v_buffer_size;

end loop;

utl_smtp.write_data( v_mailconn, utl_tcp.crlf );
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, LAST_BOUNDARY);
utl_smtp.write_data (v_mailconn, utl_tcp.crlf );
dbms_lob.fileclose(src_file);
utl_smtp.close_data (v_mailconn);
utl_smtp.quit(v_mailconn);

EXCEPTION

   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      utl_smtp.quit(v_mailconn);
  RAISE;

END;
```